# How to install package manualy on a ROS compiled from code

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am currently installing packages manually when missing dependencies are occurring on compile

is there a way to make this easier ? I mean if it is possible to compile ros from code, there must be some alternative to aptitude ?

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346096/how-to-install-package-manualy-on-a-ros-compiled-from-code/) by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run the following command in the root of your workspace folder, it will search through all the `package.xml` files in the `src` directory and automatically install missing package binaries using `apt`:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r
```

Make sure `rosdep` is up to date first:

```
rosdep update
```

Any package included as a `<depend>`, `<exec_depend>`, `<build_depend>` etc. in any `package.xml` will be found by the command, so make sure all packages you need to build or run a package are listed it its `package.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2020-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-07**:
Note: this will only install *system dependencies* when building ROS from source.

It will not install / fetch missing ROS packages.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-07**:
s@#t...ok well I'll do this manualy

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-08**:
No, that's not necessarily needed. I just wanted to draw attention to the fact that what @robustify writes is not a complete answer to your question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-08**:
If we're talking about packages that have been released, you could try something like this:

```
rosinstall_generator <the_package> --rosdistro <your_distro> --deps --tar --exclude RPP > the_package_deps.rosinstall
```

this will ask `rosinstall_generator` to generate a list of files/repositories to download (actually: `.tar` files) which you then merge into your workspace using `wstool`. Then you can run `rosdep`, which installs the system dependencies, and then you can run `catkin_make`.

See also #q346123 for a recent Q&A about this procedure.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-09**:
I am talking about raspbery pi 4 and the fact that I had to compile ROS from the appropriate tutorial

I'll try to use rosdep, but I am pretty sure, I'll end up doing this on my RPI3 in the end :-(

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-09**:
-bash: rosinstall_generator: command not found

but 'rodep update' and 'rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r' installed some packages

then I could go further installing hector slam...it installed opncv deps  , but I keep having unmet dependencies, so I install them manualy

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-09**:
`rosinstall_generator` is not installed by default. On platforms without `.deb` packages, you'd have to install it using `pip install rosinstall_generator`. The same goes for `rosdep`.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
ok but I have an error about some package being not homogenous and such, I checked the logs and there are some compilation errors, I decided to stop tinkering with an unfinished ros package, I'll try on a RPI3 ready to go image

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:\

> error about some package being not homogenous and such

that's most likely an error printed by `catkin_make`, which it prints whenever you have packages with a build type other than `catkin` in your workspace. It should also tell you to use `catkin_make_isolated` to build workspaces like that (`catkin_tools` can also build them).

> I decided to stop tinkering with an unfinnished ros version

ROS Melodic is far from "unfinished". It's in production use in countless applications.

RPi support (all of them actually, not just the 4) is community contributed. That doesn't mean it's any less valuable, but unless someone from the community decides to keep it up to date, there are bound to be problems on newer platforms.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
ok but since I added packages manualy, I have no idea what to do, do I remove them ? I am a complete ROS noob
and I 'd rather avoid compile stuffs, I have done enough manual add/compile... yet I am nowhere on the path of learning ROS

I'll try the ubiquity image

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
actualy I could make my lidar work but now I want hector slam to be installed, it ends up with some weird QT compilation issues...digging in google, it appears nobody had that error on ROS, so maybe I reached the limit of working pakages on RPI4/melodic